# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'BY sort_order ASC' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\models\Category.php:12

Помогите,пожалуйста. Я кодировала интернет-магазин.

Проблема в файле Category.php

```
<?php 
class Category
{
    public static function getCategoriesList()
    {
        
        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $categoryList = array();

        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category'
        . 'ORDER BY sort_order ASC');

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $categoryList;
    }
}
```

Файл Db.php

```
<?php 
class Db
{

    введите сюда код
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);

        $options = [
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // сообщать об ошибках
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, // чтобы не писать каждый раз
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // для удобства
        ];
        

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password'], $options);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        return $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: пробел перед `order` поставьте. и читайте в следующий раз сообщения об ошибке. если не ясно что не так в синтаксисе, то выведите полученный запрос в лог или на экран.

Comment: У вас есть таблица `categoryORDER` ?

Comment: у меня есть таблица category

Comment: нет,есть таблица просто category. Спасибо вам, я поняла))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что не хватает пробела перед `ORDER BY`. Если убрать конкатенацию строк (зачем она здесь, кстати, только для сокращения общей длины строки?), то получится вот что:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM categoryORDER BY sort_order ASC');
```

А должно быть так:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY sort_order ASC');
```

Поэтому SQL и ругается на синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо , Andre Polykanine. Теперь возникла другая ошибка,ругается, что в 1 строке ошибка                                         $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, price, image, is_new FROM product   //1ая строка
         WHERE status = "1"
         ORDER BY id DESC 
         LIMIT   $count');                                                                                                                                     Я руководствовалась по урокам на ютубе по mvc и будучи начинающей просто повторяла за уроками,не вдаваясь в подробности. Так всё трудно

Comment: Динара, не отчаивайтесь, у вас всё получится! Смотрите, если вот это: `//1ая строка` у вас было в запросе, то SQL и будет ругаться, ибо у него другой синтаксис комментариев (с `--`).